# outline doesn't work correctly in Safari and iOS phones

Tags: html, css, safari, outline

I try to use the below code to have a circle with a border and an outline with an offset. I get good results on android phones and chrome browsers on Mac. But It doesn't work correctly on Safari and iOS phones.

I expect this in the Safari and iOS phones same as Chrome:

[image]

But get this result:

[image]

My codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color:#E7E9EB;
}
#myDIV {
  border: 20px solid black;
  border-radius:300px;
  outline: 20px solid green;
  outline-offset: 20px;

  height:200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  padding:100px;
  font-size: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The border-radius Property</h1>

<div id="myDIV">
<p>A demonstration of how to add rounded corners.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Comment: simply add `outline-radius`

Comment: @galalem It doesn't work. Qoute: "This property can only be used in Firefox2-87 (till march 2021) and from Firefox 88, outline-property follows the shape created by border-radius automatically, so this property is no longer needed."

Comment: A known bug in Safari. See e.g. https://caniuse.com/?search=outline